# Можно ли иметь один ssh ключ на несколько устройств?

Tags: git, github, ssh

У меня есть 2 компьютера, могу ли я 1 ssh ключ использовать сразу на двух устройствах для работы с гитом и ssh сервером?
(из расчета на то что я не буду пользоваться 2мя этими устройствами одновременно)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно и даже можно пользоваться ими одновременно.